# PHP "Warning: Illegal string offset" on all my table rows

Tags: php, html, sql

As the title says I get an error where my database rows show the illegal string offset error in my rows if I try to output them from my SQL. Would like some help in resolving this.

[image]

This is the table I am trying to output:

Table Name: for_lease

[image]

I have three php files that connect to each other. Also this is already connected to the phpmyadmin so ill only show snippets.

**for_lease.php** (outputs the table)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('for_lease.vc.php');
?>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 bg-color-white shadow border-radius"><!-- List { -->
          <div class="row bg-color-dark-gold border-top-radius">
            <div class="col-md-12 color-white section-title-bar">
              <span class="ion-ios-list-outline"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;FOR LEASE
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
            <a href="for_lease_add.php" class="color-dark-gold">
            <span class="ion-plus-round"></span> ADD FOR LEASE</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
          </div>

          <table class="table table-hover spacer">
            <thead align="center">
              <td></td>
              <td>NAME</td>
              <td>TYPE</td>
              <td>PRICE</td>
              <td>CONDITION</td>
              <td>CREATED</td>
            </thead>

            <?php foreach($lstProperty as $rowProperty) { ?>
              <tr align="center">
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                    echo($rowProperty['lease_name']);
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                    echo($rowProperty['lease_type']);
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                    echo($rowProperty['lease_price']);
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                    echo($rowProperty['lease_condition']);
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                    echo( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($rowProperty['createddate']) ));
                  ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>

        </div><!-- List { -->
    </div>
  </div> <!--row-->
```

**for_lease.vc.php** (accessing the database and the class with the SQL)

```
<?php

    require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

    require_once($routePath . "_mc/Property.mc.php");
    $mcProperty = new Property_MC();

    $lstProperty = $mcProperty->SelectObj_ByLeaseId($db);
?>
```

**Property.mc.php** (contains the class with select SQL)

```
<?php

Class Property_MC {
    public function SelectObj_ByLeaseId($db) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " SELECT leaseid, lease_type, lease_name, lease_address, lease_price, lease_condition, lease_description, recstatus, createddate
      FROM for_lease"
  );

  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $row;
}
}

?>
```

I checked that maybe somehow the output is read as a array, not a string hence the error, but I am not sure where in my code it is affected, or maybe theres something missing for the output to be read as a string.

Will appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your method `SelectObj_ByLeaseId` returns only 1 property, the variable `$lstProperty` is an array of the fields associated with that property.  So doing a `foreach` over that array is actually iterating over the individual values of the property (which are most likely strings) which is why you get the illegal offset.

Just remove the `foreach` loop.

Comment: im trying to follow what you said, if i remove the foreach i cannot then use the Select SQL i have. also an error occurs if there i just remove it.

Comment: OK - so you want the `SelectObj_ByLeaseId` to return all the properties - then change `fetch()` to `fetchAll()` so it returns a list - and keep the foreach you have at the moment.  Just as a comment though `SelectObj_ByLeaseId` would to me read as though it is meant to return 1 row, so perhaps change it to reflect it's true purpose.

Comment: wow what a quick fix, thanks for pointing out what i have overlooked